# How should I modify roasting time in this roast goose recipe?

Tags: roasting, poultry, stuffing, goose, recipe-changing

I have an 11½-lb goose that I would like to roast.  I'm planning to use a technique from Cook's Illustrated magazine, which calls for a 10- to 12-lb bird, and for which the roasting proceeds as follows:

1. Stuff and truss goose
2. Roast breast side down at 325°F (≈160°C) for 1½ hours
3. Flip to breast side up and roast for a further 1¼–1½ hours, until drumsticks feel soft and skin has puffed around breast & thighs
4. Increase heat to 400°F (≈200°C) and roast for 15 minutes to brown & crisp skin

However, I do not plan to stuff the goose.  I assume, because of the the reduced thermal mass, that I need to reduce the cooking time;  but I don't know by how much, or for which step (2, 3, or both) I should reduce the time.   What would be the best way to modify this recipe for an unstuffed goose?